# Using mysqldump 5.7 to backup 5.6 database

Tags: mysql

Is it ok to use the mysqldump 5.7 client to backup a MySQL 5.6 database?  If so is there anything to be aware of?

Taking it a step further, is it ok to use the MySQL 5.7 client to load the aforementioned dump back into a MySQL 5.6 database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both should be fine.

Where you'd be more likely to get into trouble would be using the 5.6 (or earlier) utilities on a 5.7 database.   Within MySQL 5.x, the bundled utilities are expected to be backwards compatible, but not forwards compatible.  As a rule, the newer versions of the tools are always preferable.

The exception to this would be bugs, of course.  The versions of `mysqldump` that shipped with early 5.6 server releases did not work correctly with 5.5 and earlier, but this was subsequently fixed, and the error was not subtle -- it just didn't work at all.